# Apparent timestamp inconsistency on asked questions

Tags: discussion, questions, timestamps

When I look for questions with certain tags, I see questions that have a recent timestamp for when they were asked.  But quite often I know this question by this user was asked much earlier (sometimes days) than what is shown.  When I check out the question there are no edits, comments, or anything else that would indicate a change.  And even if there were, comments would not be a reason to change when the original question was asked.

When I search for new questions, that is what I expect to get, in chronological order.  So what does constitute a change in the timestamp?

I searched the site and could not find an explanation.  If I overlooked it, my apologies.

EDIT.

One thing I forgot to add was when I go back and check out the question, it shows the actual date that the question was asked.

Comment: Sometimes users ask a question, delete it and then ask the exact same question again.

Comment: One thing I forgot to add was when I go back and check out the question, it shows the `actual date` that the question was asked.

Comment: @WJS I think we'll need an example in that case.

Comment: Are you a frequent *Back button* user?

Comment: @rene  Yes I am. And I also notice that sometimes my reputation fluctuates back and forth depending on the particular post I am reviewing.  Perhaps this is a caching issue (although I try to keep my browser cache to a minimum).

Comment: Using the Back button on the sites here is going to give you guaranteed stale and weird results. Most stuff will come from your browser, some stuff might come from an upstream but also stale cache and some bits might update live as it is connected to a websocket. On SE sites you should navigate going forward, that is: click a link to load the view you're interested in. Using your browser history is doomed to fail in many awkward ways.

Comment: @rene Then that may be the cause of what I am seeing.  I guess I will have to modify how I browse the site.  Thanks!